# 7 years from date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to subtract 7 years from the date...

I tried this and it did not work :( what am I doing wrong?

```
strtotime("-7 year", strtotime(date("Y")))
```

this would echo out `1131498720` the answer I am looking for is `2005`

I forgot to mention that "-7" is a variable `$x = -7`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

strtotime returns a unix timestamp (seconds since Jan 1/1970). 1131498720 corresponds to Nov 8/2005, which IS 7 years in the past.

Since you're just substracting years, why not simply

```
$seven_years_ago = date('Y') - 7;
```

Comment: so `- $var` in that case. It's not rocket science, just basic subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$str = date('Y', strtotime(date('Y') . " -7year"));
echo $str;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/nX5kL5gF)

Comment: `$str = date('Y', strtotime(date('Y') . "-".$var." year"));` as Marc mentioned as well. Just do a simple subtraction as in Marc's answer, as that's the simpler solution.